# Selenium WebDriver -- Unable to click on hyperlink, click goes to the other element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on Website hyperlink, the click goes to Recently used pages.

1. Tried with CSS locator of Website icon [which works in the lower environment as it doesn't have Recently used pages] reference in it.
2. Tried with XPath Locator[including custom XPath], still, the click goes to another item.
3. Tried name locator.
4. Used Actions class for clicking.
5. Allowed the page to load completely by using sleep and WebDriver wait.
6. Located the element and send Enter keys, still Recently used pages is clicked.
7. Tried to click it using coordinates.

Thought of ChromeDriver issue but the issue persists in Firefox too.

Tried below XPath:

```
html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div 

//div[2]/div/a/div
```

Code snippet:

```
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon.siteadmin"));
elementToClick.click();

WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon.siteadmin"));
(JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().x+")");
elementToClick.click();

WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon.siteadmin"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(elementToClick);
actions.click().perform();  

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(elementToClick, 40, 207).click().build().perform();
```

**Result**: It clicks on Recently Used Pages, and it yields a result of Recently used pages instead of Website.

[UI Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0qdJ.png)

[Development Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpvft.png)

Comment: Can you update the HTML & code block & error stack trace as text in the question area for better analysis?

Comment: Please put what did you tried so far as well

Comment: Can you try using this xpath `//a[@title='Websites']/div/div[@class='title']` and let me know the outcome

Comment: @NarendraR - Thanks for the reply, but the solution fails to work. It clicks on Recently used pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath(“//a[contains(@title, ‘Websites’)]”)).click()
```

If this doesn’t work use the above XPath in combination with one of the moves to element paths above and then use click.

Comment: It finda the element but the click goes somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Hope It Helps you:

```
.//div[@id='box_2']/a/div[@class='icon siteadmin']/div[1]
```

Comment: It finda the element but the click goes somewhere else.